# Can a subgroup be not equal to the group?

Tags: group-theory

Let A be the group of positive rational numbers under multiplication.
Prove that A is isomorphic to a subgroup B such that A does not equal B.

So I know how prove isomorphisms.(define mapping, prove 1-1, prove onto, and prove operation-preserving). However, I am thrown by the fact that the subgroup does not equal A. Is it that the order is not equal? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you may be able to map 2 to 3 and 3 to 2.

Comment: $x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @RobArthan the mapping $x \mapsto x^2 $ is not one-to-one nor onto. So it is not an isomorphism candidate that works.

Comment: $x \mapsto x^2$ is one-to-one on $A$ (since the elements of $A$ are positive) and you don't want it to be onto (you want the image $B$ not to be equal to $A$).

Comment: @RobArthan If it is not onto, how is it an isomorphism?

Comment: It does not map onto $A$ the set of all positive rational numbers, but it does map onto its image, $B$, the set of positive rational squares.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Start out by listing some subgroups of A: What's the smallest subgroup containing 1 and 2?  1 and 3?  1 and 2 and 3?  Can any of these 3 be isomorphic to A?  Can you find a subgroup that is a better potential candidate?

Comment: I don't see how your suggested approach will help.

Comment: The 3 examples can't be isomorphic because they're finitely generated.  A good subgroup to look at would be one that isn't finitely generated.

Comment: That's a bit of a roundabout hint, but I see how it *might* help. Note that the OP's question is about $\Bbb{Q}_{+}$ under multiplication so $1$ is in any subgroup.